# ХристианИн, но крестьЯнин

Tags: фонетика

"Христианство" и "крестьянство" — слова отличаются друг от друга мало (не по смыслу, а грамматически), но при этом почему-то "христианИн", но "крестьЯнин". Это что, просто исторически сложилось?

Answer (score 1):

Слово христианин восходит к греческому christiano's(опекаемый Христом) и произносится с  ударением на последний слог,а в общеславянском языке оно воспринято как содержащее корень крест + суфф.-а'н-ин наподобие киевля'нин. В др.-русском языке слово крестьянин было параллельным к слову христианин с тождественным значением,  с 14 века начинает употребляться как "сельский житель, землепашец", а до этого имело смысл "житель русской земли"(в противоположность иноверцам), а ещё раньше - христианин, крещёный, в болг. и сейчас крестьянин-христианин.

Comment: Так вопрос-то был об ударении. Почему в настолько схожих словах разные ударения

Comment: Так и я про ударение. В греческом слове (христиани'н)ударение на последний слог, как во всех греч.прилагательных( christiano's), в русском по традиции ударного суффикса сущ. -а'нин-я'нин-.